# What things are zealots allowed to do?

Tags: halacha, zealotry

If a zealot catches a Jewish man sleeping with a non-Jewish woman he can kill them based on הבועל את הגויה קנאין פוגעין בו. Are there any other halachot like that? Meaning are there any other things which normal halacha is one way but for a קנאי it is different?

Comment: Can you source that he can kill them?  That Pinchas did once doesn't mean anybody else can now, and my understanding is that the rabbis put rather a few restrictions around that apparent precedent.

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in the Mishna [Sanhedrin 9:6](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%98_%D7%95) ([English](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9671&st=&pgnum=284)):

> הגונב את הקסווה, והמקלל בקוסם, והבועל ארמית--קנאין פוגעין בהן.  כוהן ששימש בטומאה--אין אחיו הכוהנים מביאין אותו לבית דין, אלא פרחי כהונה מוציאין אותו חוץ לעזרה, ומוציאין את מוחו בגזרין.‏
>   If one stole a service-vessel, or cursed [the Name of God] by enchantment, or had sexual connexion with an Aramaic woman, the zealots may lay hold of him. If a priest served in uncleanness, his brethren the priests do not bring him to the court, but the young men of the priesthood take him forth without the Temple Court and split his skull open with logs.

The Rambam rules accordingly in Hilkhot Sanhedrin 18:6.

Comment: N.B. footnote 4 on the beginning of the [following page](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9671&st=&pgnum=285).